# Figma и Django? Как соеденить полученную картинку с логикой?

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, figma

Кто знает как соединить в единое целое дизайн сайта созданный в Figma с логикой на Django, чтобы все корректно работало. В ответе жду просто общее объяснение.

Comment: эээмм....верстаете...интегрируете шаблон в джанго... или я чего то не понимаю?.. насколько я понимаю фигма это инструмент для прототипирования...не больше ни меньше

Comment: `Figma` — это программа для дизайнеров. Всё что может извлечь из неё разработчик — это сомнительно сгенерированный `CSS`. Вы не сможете соединить дизайн из `Figma` ни с логикой на `Django`, ни даже с обычной `HTML`-страницей. Вы должны вручную сверстать `HTML`, добавить `CSS` и оформить это в виде `Django`-шаблона. А к шаблонам написать представления, то есть непосредственно логику. Как уже и писали выше, `Figma` — всего лишь инструмент для прототипирования.

Comment: Спасибо большое за ответ

Comment: Мне именно это и нужно было узнать, ведь адекватного объяснения я нигде найти не смог